# Pie chart with pandas & matplot lib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a pie chart of the titanic survivor data. I have been trying to plot this as a pie chart but I keep getting a KeyError 0. How can I fix this?

```
figure(1, figsize=(6,6))
ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
s_survival = (titanic_data.Survived[titanic_data.Embarked == 'S'][titanic_data.Survived == 1].value_counts()
         ) / survivors.sum()
c_survival = (titanic_data.Survived[titanic_data.Embarked == 'C'][titanic_data.Survived == 1].value_counts()
         ) / survivors.sum()
q_survival = (titanic_data.Survived[titanic_data.Embarked == 'Q'][titanic_data.Survived == 1].value_counts()
         ) / survivors.sum()
labels = ['s_survival', 'c_survival', 'q_survival']
sizes = [s_survival, c_survival, q_survival]
pie(sizes, explode=None, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=False, startangle=90)
title('Survivor Percentage from Embarked Port')
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

StackTrace :

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-a8c68ae3422f> in <module>()
     11 sizes = [s_survival, c_survival, q_survival]
     12 # add a list zip here
---> 13 plt.pie(sizes, explode=None, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=False, startangle=90)
     14 title('Survivor Percentage from Embarked Port')
//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in pie(x, explode, labels, colors, autopct, pctdistance, shadow, labeldistance, startangle, radius, counterclock, wedgeprops, textprops, center, frame, hold, data)
   3135                      radius=radius, counterclock=counterclock,
   3136                      wedgeprops=wedgeprops, textprops=textprops, center=center,
-> 3137                      frame=frame, data=data)
   3138     finally:
   3139         ax.hold(washold)

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1810                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1811                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1812             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1813         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1814         if pre_doc is None:

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in pie(self, x, explode, labels, colors, autopct, pctdistance, shadow, labeldistance, startangle, radius, counterclock, wedgeprops, textprops, center, frame)
   2546         """
   2547 
-> 2548         x = np.asarray(x).astype(np.float32)
   2549 
   2550         sx = float(x.sum())

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    472 
    473     """
--> 474     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    475 
    476 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    558     def __getitem__(self, key):
    559         try:
--> 560             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    561 
    562             if not lib.isscalar(result):

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
   1909         try:
   1910             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 1911                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   1912         except KeyError as e1:
   1913             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3234)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2931)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3891)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6527)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6465)()

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error message?